# Evaluating list inside list in a table

Tags: list-manipulation

I'm stuck with a List and Table command. I want to evaluate  $F[x,y]$  and get all the possible configurations, knowing that x and y are lists.
How I should evaluate this correctly in Mathematica? and thanks in advance!

`F[x_, y_] :=Flatten[Table[{a, b, c, d}, {a, 1, 2}, {b, 0, x - a + 1}, {c, 1, 2}, {d, 1, y - 1}], 3]; x = {14, 9, 7, 5, 10}; y = {1, 3, 2, 4, 5};`

Comment: If you want all possible combinations of list elements what is typically useful is `Outer`, e.g.: `Flatten[Outer[List, {1, 2}, x, {1, 2}, y], 3]`. Does this give the output you want?

Comment: Andrzej, I think `Flatten[Outer[F, x, y], 2]` is another good answer to the problem. Why don't you add it?

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you want integers as the input to the function `F[x_,y_]` and that you want to apply them to all combinations of the lists, `x` and `y`.

Continue on with your use of `Table` and apply it to `x` and `y`. `Table` is very powerful and can accept lists in addition to iteration parameters.

```
Table[F[x, y], {x, {14, 9, 7, 5, 10}}, {y, {1, 3, 2, 4, 5}}]
```

Comment: Thanks, it's work but i want all the results look like { {1, 0, 1, 1}, {1, 0, 1, 2}, {1, 0, 2, 1}, {1, 0, 2, 2},........ } bcz i get sum of lists inside a lists{{{}, {{1, 0, 1, 1}, {1, 0, 1, 2}, {1, 0, 2, 1}, {1, 0, 2, 2}, {1, 1, 
    1, 1}........}}}}

Comment: Wrap the result with another `Flatten`. `Flatten` accepts a third argument indicating how many times it should be applied.  `Flatten[Table[F[x, y], {x, {14, 9}}, {y, {3}}], 2]`

Comment: Thanks a lot! for the help.